# How should the standard factorial function behave?

Tags: math, factorial

I got many answers for this when I Googled "How to find factorial of a number"...

One of those examples is...

```
private double getFactorial(double f){
    if ( f == 0 ) 
        return 1;
    return (f * getFactorial(f - 1));
}
```

And it works... However, the Windows Calculator surprised me: It works for decimal numbers as well!!

For example: On the Windows Calculator, the factorial of `0.5` is `0.886226925`...

Is that the desired behavior? Is the factorial defined for non-integers?

Comment: Actually, no, that should not work for a non-integral number. The factorial generalized to all numbers (including non-integers) is (almost) the same as the Gamma Function - which is not that easy to compute. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Comment: @ Jigar Joshi pls see edit.....

Comment: You should not compare doubles exactly. Also, for non-integers this never returns (in practice: most likely throws stack overflow exception).

Comment: There are ways to extend factorial to rational and even complex numbers, e.g. the Gamma function and the Pi function.

Comment: Before down voting add a comment for that...

Comment: I don't agree with the downvote and close votes either. It's a perfectly valid question to ask if the factorial is defined for non-integers in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making my comment an answer:

The factorial can be generalized to nearly all numbers (real/complex/non-integral) via the ***[Gamma Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)***.

The only points for which it is still undefined are for negative integers due to singularities. (This is easy to see by reversing the recursion identity for the factorial. Going from `0!` to `(-1)!` leads to a divide by zero.)

Obviously, your code will work only for integers. For anything else it will go into an infinite recursion and cause a stackoverflow.

---

For integers, it's easy to compute it with a simple loop or a recursion. But for anything else, it's much harder to do.

There are two main algorithms for evaluating the factorial/Gamma Function at non-integral points:

- [Stirling's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) combined with the usual recursion property.
- [Lanczos approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_approximation)

Wikipedia has an implementation of the latter in Python.

Comment: Actually, the Gamma function is *not* defined for all numbers, only for all complex numbers *except* non-positive integers.

Comment: The negative integer cases fall under the same category as a simple divide-by-zero since the `1/x!` is an entire function (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the factorial of a number, it should be declared with a long/int return type and a long/int type parameter; since factorials only work for non-negative integers.
Example

```
private long getFactorial(int f) {

   if ( f == 0 ) 
        return 1; //0!=1
   return (f * getFactorial(f - 1)); //basic recursive formula

}
```

Your code goes into an infinite loop (or at least a stack overflow), say, when you try to find (-1.1)! or (0.001)! ...

Also I am not sure what goes on in the windows calculator (say, 1.5! returns 1.3293403881791370204736256125059) but I think this would help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Answer (score 0):

Factorial can be generalized to real numbers using [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). Let G(x) be gamma of x and P(x) generalized factorial of x (also known as the [Pi function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Pi_function)). The relation between G(x) and P(x) is P(x)=x*G(x).

You can [find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Particular_values) that G(0.5) is sqrt(pi)=sqrt(3.141592...). Hence P(0.5)=0.5*sqrt(3.141592...)=0.5*1.772453...=0.886226...

Note that there is no direct connection between the fact that the famous pi number happens to be part of the value of G(x) and the fact that the other function is called Pi function.

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, the factorial function is a function defined exactly on all non-negative integers.

The gamma function is not the factorial function. It is a function on the complex numbers.
gamma(n) computes (n-1)! for n a positive integer.

The factorial function should behave precisely as you have designed it. No more, no less.